# Convert HTML file to Excel file using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, xml, excel

I have an HTML string where I want to convert to an Excel file. I have tried the following code, but I cannot see any data in Excel.

```
var tableToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,';
    var template = '<html xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office"xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40"><head><!--[if gte mso 9]>    <xml><x:ExcelWorkbook><x:ExcelWorksheets><x:ExcelWorksheet><x:Name>{worksheet}</x:Name><x:WorksheetOptions><x:DisplayGridlines/></x:WorksheetOptions></x:ExcelWorksheet></x:ExcelWorksheets></x:ExcelWorkbook></xml><![endif]--></head><body><table>{table}</table></body></html>';
    var base64 = function(s) {
        return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s)));
    };
    var format = function(s, c) {
        return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) {return c[p]; });
    }
    return function(table, name) {
        if (!table.nodeType)
            table = document.getElementById(table);
        var ctx = {
            worksheet: name || 'Worksheet',
            table: table.innerHTML
        };
        window.location.href = uri + base64(format(template, ctx));
    }
})()
```

If I run the above code, Excel is downloading but I can't see any data in Excel.
Is there any other solution where I can convert an HTML file to an Excel file?

Comment: If all else fails try CSV perhaps. Not ideal. But it's an alternative

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will do the trick?
 [jQuery - table2excel](http://www.jqueryscript.net/table/Export-Html-Table-To-Excel-Spreadsheet-using-jQuery-table2excel.html)
Looked on CDNJS and found [TableExport](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/TableExport) too, so you can reference remote JS library in script tag...
Here it is on [**GitHub**](https://github.com/clarketm/TableExport). **Follow their install guide...**